# How to extract middle characters from a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, function, excel-formula

I need a excel function code that would enable to me extract certain characters in the middle of a cell.

So in cell A74 is:

```
1625362674848-cdpresent-auths_ol_mart-auths1837372
```

So I Need to extract "auths_ol_mart" into a separate column

I have tried this:

```
=MID(A2, SEARCH("-",A2) + 1, SEARCH("-",A2,SEARCH("-",A2)+1) - SEARCH("-",A2) - 1)
```

Now the problem is this only gets "cdpresent". I am not quite sure how this is done.

more examples include:

```
3837463747-cdpresent-avaya_op_history-clm1827489
```

I want "avaya_op_history"

```
3734279458-cdpresent-uk_score_app-clm9377233
```

I want "uk_score_app"

Thank you all

Comment: @urdearboy Thanks for your fast response, I only have this one example and I want to extract using the dashes. I can give another example but it would be the same format. I hope this makes sense

Comment: @urdearboy yes you are right there are many records. I will give more examples but they are roughly the same format - I will update this question

Comment: What version of excel?

Comment: @urdearboy Yes you are exactly right they are all between the 2nd and 3rd dash, it is constant for all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this worksheet formula:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1,99),FIND("-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,FIND("-",A1)+1)+1,99))-1)
```

If you use the Formula Evaluation tool, you will be able to see how this works.

If you prefer a UDF, you can use:

```
Function betweenDashes(S As String) As String
    betweenDashes = Split(S, "-")(2)
End Function
```

**Edit *(20MAR2020)***

Another formula to return the third item in the string, if you have Excel 2013+ and the `FILTERXML` function:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[3]")
```

or, if you prefer, the next to last item:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[last()-1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to formula is `Text to Columns` with hyphen (-) as a delimiter. You get what you are looking for in the 3rd column:

[image: text to columns]